# How to Re-arch the array values

Tags: arrays

I have a Typescript file and returning an array to use in binding in *ngFor.

OLD:

```
getYear(): any {
    return [
        { name: "2014", value: 2014 },
        { name: "2015", value: 2015 },
        { name: "2016", value: 2016 },
        { name: "2017", value: 2017 },
        { name: "2018", value: 2018 },
        { name: "2019", value: 2019 },
        { name: "2020", value: 2020 },
    ];
}
```

*this is hard coded values*

Now, how do I make this type of array like the OLD one I'm using before?

NEW:

```
return [2014,2015,2016,....];
```

*this array is from the server side.*

Answer (score 0):

I created this as the container:

```
years = Array<{ name: string , value: number }> = [];
```

Then I populated the container by the new Values I get in the service.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.yearValues.length; i++) {
            this.years.push({ name: this.yearValues[i], value: +this.yearValues[i] });
        }
        this.optionsYear = this.years;
```